# Screw Modifier with different materials on faces

Tags: materials, screw-modifier

I need to set a different material on the blue marked faces.
this material linked to the angle.
Thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: With the screw modifier you can't keep these faces. You'll have better luck with a simple deform modifier

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is currently not possible with the *Screw Modifier* sadly. The modifier is not material slot aware, it has no *Material Offset* options like *Solidify* nor can *Material Slots* be stored on edges.

One possible workaround is duplicating the object, removing the *Screw Modifier* and assigning a new material to the new instance. Make sure the material slots are linked to *Object* (rather than *Object Data*) in the dropdown to the right.

[image]

You can still keep shape in sync between the two because they are duplicates, and you can now adjust section from the two caps too.

Optionally add a *Mirror Modifier*, or rotate another instanced duplicated to fill the opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Create a plane and use the screw modifier 360° with 2 materials pink and green, create an object cube with 2 materials pink and green. Use this cube in the boolean modifier to cut the "screwed" plane.

Comment: Could you add some explaination or a link to the solution? thx

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Create a plane and use the screw modifier 360° with 2 materials pink and green, create an object cube with 2 materials pink and green. Use this cube in the boolean modifier to cut the "screwed" plane.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the *Material Properties* tab, hit the *+* icon in the upper right corner and add a new material slot, set the material you want. Select the faces and click *Assign*.

Comment: You can't individually select faces generated by modifiers without applying them, so this doesn't work without first applying the *Screw Modifier*